# Sending JSON-LD markup with mailgun doesn't work

Tags: mailgun, json-ld, google-schemas

I'm trying to send email via SMTP with Mailgun. The email has an application/ld+json markups `EventReservation`. If I send the email with mailgun smtp, the markups does not work, if I send the same template via google.scripts, the markups works fine.

What is the problem?

This is my template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prenotazine TiPrenota</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "5aa46b79-140d-491e-a1db-568ec1c423bd",
      "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "Mario Rossi
      },
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "Ragione sociale attivita",
        "startDate": "2017-03-27T12:30:00",
        "location": {
          "@type": "Place",
          "name": "nome ragione sociale",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "viale amore 100, cesena, 47521, Italia"
          },
          "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
            "latitude": "44,490501",
            "longitude": "12,281881"
          }
        },
        "performer":"Reservation"
      },
      "modifyReservationUrl": "https://www.domionio.it/?tokenid=5aa46b79-140d-491e-a1db-568ec1c423bd"
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Testo emeil
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have followed this [steps](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#how-to-start-sending-email) on how to send an email using SMTP.

Run this:

```
# Swaks is an smtp of CURL, install it first:
curl http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/files/swaks-20130209.0/swaks -o swaks
# Set the permissions for the script so you can run it
chmod +x swaks
# It's based on perl, so install perl
sudo apt-get -y install perl
# now send!
./swaks --auth \
        --server smtp.mailgun.org \
        --au postmaster@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
        --ap 3kh9umujora5 \
        --to bar@example.com \
        --h-Subject: "Hello" \
        --body 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

You can find your SMTP credentials for each domain on your [domains tab](https://mailgun.com/app/domains).

Comment: I can send email via SMTP, my problem is that they do not see the markups area inside the mail